# ubuntu 14.04 LTS nvidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have a gtx 780 nvidia graphics card and i would like to use cuda. To do so, I need the `nvidia` drivers rather than `xorg server` drivers. The problem I have is that every time I install a driver from nvidia my ubuntu boots with black screen printing a message: `prob failed [some numbers]`. In order to avoid reinstalling ubuntu each time I boot in recovery mode and then I just `sudo purge nvidia*` and reinstall the `xorg server` drivers. What i have tried so far:

- `sudo apt-get nvidia-304`
- same with `352` nvidia driver(is the latest)
- installed cuda which it automatically installs the nvidia drivers(again failed)

What can I do to make the nvidia drivers work?

Comment: Open Software & Updates app in Ubuntu and it allows to install NVIDIA driver from GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1** - Uninstall the existing NVIDIA drivers ...

Highlight the **Ubuntu entry** in the GRUB menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password.
Execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2** - Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers ...

Highlight the **Ubuntu entry** in the GRUB menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password.
Execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

In case you consider a clean installation, which I recommend because maybe there is messed up too much, add the parameter when booting from the installation media and the first time after the installation of the Ubuntu system as well. First of all install the NVIDIA drivers following the instructions from Step 2. Everything should work fine now, so  adding the parameter is obsolete.

Comment: after a clean installation of ubuntu and following step 2 i got again probe failed. Any other suggestions? This is becoming a nightmare... :/

Comment: @KostasRim : Do you have Windows or any other operating system  installed and does it boot correctly ?

Comment: yes i have windows 7 and everything is fine, i use `GRUB` to boot

Comment: @KostasRim : Does Ubuntu boot when you wait for some time after "ACPI PCC probe failed" appears ?

Comment: if i have the probe failed no, but what i normaly do is a restart then boot in recovery mode, purge the nvidia drivers and use the xorg ones. The thing is that cuda supports only nvidia drivers. It drives me nuts that i can;t install them..  Any other suggestion ? Maybe its the graphics card??

Comment: @KostasRim : Boot into BIOS and check whether there are graphics and monitor settings you can switch.

Comment: um in monitor i have a tab tha it has : `CPU Q-Fan Control` enabled,  some other for cpu fan amd profile.  chassis 1 and 2 q fan control and an `Anti sirge Support` enabled. I have a boot tab(fast boot enabled and some other options). An advanced tabs that has: CPU configuration, PCH configuration, Sata configuration, USB Configiration, platform misc configuration, onboard devices configuration, APM and network stack. Finally there is another tab AI tweaker and tools. Maybe i should post a pic? Anything in particular that you want me to search?

Comment: @KostasRim : Repeat the whole procedure (Step 1+2) from the answer, but this time add "nomodeset" instead of  "nouveau.modeset=0" to the end of the linux line.

Comment: error cant find `nomodeset` after pressing the f10 button. Thank you a lot for helping... maybe i should look at bios again? why is this even happening...

Comment: @KostasRim : This is nearly not possible - please try it again - add "nomodeset" (without quotes) to the end of the linux line ... don't forget to type a space between the last sign of the line and the parameter.

Comment: http://imgur.com/I18zCUA, http://imgur.com/jnWk9qZ,  http://imgur.com/7ADqPLmThe first picture is where i press, the second where i put the `nomodeset` and the third the error.  What is happening...? :/

Comment: @KostasRim : You placed "nomodeset" behind "the "initrd" line and not at the end of the line starting with the word "linux" ! When you did the same with "nouveau.modeset=0" it cannot work. So please repeat everything again and put"nomodeset" at the end of the linux line, then press F10 to boot ... :)

Comment: just to be sure i will place the `nouveau.modeset=0` like this: end of linux line says `$vt_handoff nouveau.modeset=0` right ?

Comment: @KostasRim Yes ... behind "$vt_handoff" put  a space and then the parameter "nouveau.modeset=0".

Comment: when i tried the nouveau and pressed f10 i got probe failed without even installing the driver. So i rebooted and tried the second approach using nomodeset.  After the driver installation and reboot i got probe failed again. The strange thing is that when i used nomodeset and before i log in to the shell the keyboard and mouse went off for some seconds. could it be bios? what is wrong with my computer :/

Comment: @KostasRim : I am running out of ideas ... this must be a hardware related thing ... maybe a cable, maybe the graphics card or the mainboard - something is completely wrong ... this solution worked on nearly all of the cases - it is the most proper and safe way to install the NVIDIA drivers - please check the hardware.

Comment: after i made a restart and booted to windows the keyboard and mouse did not work. I had to restart in order to work. give me a sec i want to try something

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you both for your time and effort. I FINALLY!!!!!!! fixed it, doing two things. First i booted in bios, and made a reset to all the changes i have made. Secondly i booted in recovery mode and changed the driver to 352. Thanks again !!!

Comment: @KostasRim : You're welcome - I am very glad that we could get this solved - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: I thank you! I couldn't resolve this without you. Btw in bios, multi monitor was enabled for a reason so it did mess up with the drivers(i am using one monitor :P).

Comment: i deleted the extra comments,  finally i can use cuda! Have a nice day!